# Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am trying to play a wav file using using Microsoft.Xna.Framework but I cannot resolve this error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Below is my code: (The error happens on line: `TitleContainer.OpenStream(dingSoundFile)`)

```
        SoundEffectInstance seiCircus;
        string dingSoundFile = "/Html/sounds/tap.wav";
        using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(dingSoundFile))
        {
            var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            //create the instance
            seiCircus = effect.CreateInstance();

            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            //play sound via the instance
            seiCircus.Play();
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws this exception? Is there an inner exception? Please post the full stack trace. Is the sound file being loaded correctly? Note that SoundEffect can only handle PCM audio 8 or 16-bit, 8KHz to 48KHz, mono or stereo. Is your wav file compatible (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashtat/archive/2010/06/03/soundeffect-creation-in-xna-game-studio-4.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks, that is the full stack trace because its a first chance exception. I think the issue is that my wav might not be PCM. Is there anywhere I can find an example PCM audio file to test with?

Comment: The XNA samples (http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started)?

Comment: Verified the PCM, still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx) for the SoundEffect.FromStream method, it looks like it throws an argument exception when the stream parameter is null. My recommendation would be to try writing an integration test or writing some defensive code to try and resolve the issue.

e.g.

**Integration Test:**

```
[Test]
public void Test() {
    string dingSoundFile = "Html/sounds/tap.wav"; //NOTE: Remove leading slash
    try {
       var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(dingSoundFile);
       Assert.IsNotNull(stream); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

or

**Defensive coding:**

```
SoundEffectInstance seiCircus;
string dingSoundFile = "Html/sounds/tap.wav"; //NOTE: Remove leading slash
try {
    using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(dingSoundFile)) {
        if(stream != null) {
           var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
           seiCircus = effect.CreateInstance();

           FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
           seiCircus.Play();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the error happens on line TitleContainer.OpenStream(dingSoundFile) so stream != null would not be reached.

Comment: It appears as though the issue is with the path of the sound file being passed in that it cannot be found or doesn't exist. You may want to put a try/catch around your using statement.

Comment: This thread seems to indicate a similar issue with trying to access the relative path for the sound file. (http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/51049/308573.aspx). I think a try/catch might help narrow down the error (at least for debugging). It also indicates that leading with a slash no longer works. You may want to try removing that from your path.